# Any perspectives on height auto for CSS3 transitions and animations?

Tags: css, w3c, css-transitions, css-animations

CSS3 transitions, transforms and animations are wonderful. They are even more now more browsers do support them.

Still there's one thing I keep asking myself: Why isn't the spec definining that CSS3 transitions and animations should handle height:auto?

It doesn't make any sense when we're moving away from fixed layouts with things like the CSS3 flexible box model and media queries.

It doesn't make any sense to use JavaScript just to set a CSS transition with a fixed height.

Now comes my question:

**Will the W3C ever specify that height:auto should be supported for CSS3 transitions and animations or can we request them to specify this?**

Comment: @BoltClock Do you know through which channel it's best to ask such things?

Comment: I turned my comments into an answer since they pretty much answer your last question.

Comment: These max-height workarounds going around now are the exact reason why not being able to animate to height: auto is a bad job done by W3C. I just don't feel that we need another era of that approach as we had IE-related hacks dominating long enough. Simply said, transition to auto is highly useful and a lot of people will need it so why not do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure why they didn't say anything about `auto` values either, but you can try asking them through their public [CSS mailing list](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style). As the transition and animation specs are still working drafts, they might just toss in some changes to address this matter. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Curious what I can propose there. I might report back with the reasoning behind the current implementation and any perspectives on it.

Answer (score 27):

You can transition max-height instead: http://jsfiddle.net/leaverou/zwvNY/

Comment: That's an amazingly useful tip – didn't think of trying that!

Comment: Thanks. I knew that one already though and its not always a substitute. For example, you need to set a max-height that's close to the real height because otherwise, you will have a noticeable delay.

Comment: Agreed, it works wonderfully if you have only very slight variance in the element height, clever technique though!

Comment: Lea - this works except in the case where you have a single div which can contain one of a number of children, and want to smoothly change the height of the container (i.e. your start *and* end states are being governed by different `height: auto` declarations)

Answer (score 3):

I think I've found a solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/adambiggs/MAbD3/

My workaround is to transition max-height to the exact content height for a nice smooth animation, then use a transitionEnd callback to set max-height to 9999px so the content can resize freely.

Comment: Once you use some JavaScript to do it, you might as well just scrap the max-height "hack" and get->set the height instead.

Comment: @adam Your solution seems to be a great alternative! Would like to upvote it twice. Do you have written a blog post about it somewhere?

Comment: @mystrdat I agree that using JavaScript isn't ideal... but if you simply get/set the height, you'll need to keep track of any content changes or window resizes that affect the content's height later on. With this "hack" your content will resize freely after the animation.

Comment: @DADU Actually this would make a pretty good blog post... But first I'll need to start a blog!

Comment: @Adam aha you're one of those few without one! Though I must admit I'm in that group as well.